# How to calculate how many rows left until reach next value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
     'one_hot'
1        0   
2        1
3        0
4        0
5        0
6        1
```

I am wondering if there is a function that allows me to count the rows left to reach the next `1`  creating a new column. So the output would be a column like:

```
     'one_hot'    'new_col'
1        0           1
2        1           0  
3        0           3       
4        0           2
5        0           1
6        1           0
```

The comments so far written are good for when the last 'one_hot' value is a `1`, but what if it was a `0`? Is there anything that can be done? Ideally I would count the length of the piece of dataframe since the last `1` and use this to fil and

Comment: What if the last value in 'one_hot' is 0?

Comment: Performance is important?

Comment: @taras that's what I've just realised!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#mask for filter out last 0 group
mask = df['one_hot'].iloc[::-1].cumsum().ne(0)[::-1]
#compare by value to mask
a = df['one_hot'] == 0
#create groups with inverse Series
b = a[::-1].cumsum()
#count only rows by mask, assign to new column
c = (b-b.where(~a).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)).where(mask, 0)
df['new'] = c

print (df)
   one_hot  new
1        0    1
2        1    0
3        0    3
4        0    2
5        0    1
6        1    0
```

Comment: thanks for the performance point! What if the last value of ``one_hot`` was a ``0``? How could I arrange it?

Comment: @Marisa - Added solution, but I think now performance should be worse, advatage is filter out last 0 group.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to start by reversing the sequence, check where there is a `1` and take the `cumsum` and use the result as a grouper to finally take the [`GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) of each group:

```
s = df.loc[::-1,'one_hot']
g = s.eq(1).cumsum()
df['new_col'] = s.groupby(g).cumcount().iloc[::-1]
```

---

```
print(df)

      one_hot  new_col
1        0        1
2        1        0
3        0        3
4        0        2
5        0        1
6        1        0
```